# Using document.write() to load javascript

Tags: javascript

Excuse my newb question. I'm still in the beginning stages of learning javascript. I'm not sure If I can accurately describe to you guys what i'm trying to do, but i'll try.

Is it possible to load a javascript file onto an html page?

for example. Twitter gave me code for there twitter widget, and it's a javascript widget. I want to be able to display it on my page using the document.write method. Is this possible. Here is an example.

This is the code they gave me.

```
<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<script>
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'search',
  search: '@blahblah',
  interval: 6000,
  title: 'Follow Me On Twitter',
  subject: 'blahblah',
  width: 180,
  height: 300,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#ebebeb',
      color: '#969396'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#ffffff',
      color: '#000000',
      links: '#bbbcbd'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: true,
    live: true,
    hashtags: true,
    timestamp: true,
    avatars: true,
    toptweets: true,
    behavior: 'default'
  }
}).render().start();
</script>
```

So, is it possible that I could write this to the html page like this?

```
document.write('<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script> '
    <script>
    'new TWTR.Widget({
      version: 2,
      type: 'search',
      search: 'blah',
      interval: 6000,
      title: 'Follow Me On Twitter',
      subject: '@blahBlah',
      width: 180,
      height: 300,
      theme: {
        shell: {
          background: '#ebebeb',
          color: '#969396'
        },
        tweets: {
          background: '#ffffff',
          color: '#000000',
          links: '#bbbcbd'
        }
      },
      features: {
        scrollbar: false,
        loop: true,
        live: true,
        hashtags: true,
        timestamp: true,
        avatars: true,
        toptweets: true,
        behavior: 'default'
      }
    }).render().start();
    </script> ');
```

or what I have to write each script as a seperate line like this?

```
document.write('<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script> ');
<script>
document.write('new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'search',
  search: '@BigNotch',
  interval: 6000,
  title: 'Follow Me On Twitter',
  subject: 'BigNotch',
  width: 180,
  height: 300,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#ebebeb',
      color: '#969396'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#ffffff',
      color: '#000000',
      links: '#bbbcbd'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: true,
    live: true,
    hashtags: true,
    timestamp: true,
    avatars: true,
    toptweets: true,
    behavior: 'default'
  }
}).render().start();
</script> ');   
 }
```

I tried THIS, but DW gave me a syntax error. Here is the ENTIRE script i'm writing.

```
  <script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function changTwitter() {
var currentTime = new Date().getHours();    

 if (7 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 17) {

       document.write('<' + 'script>
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'search',
  search: '@BigNotch',
  interval: 6000,
  title: 'Follow Me On Twitter',
  subject: 'BigNotch',
  width: 180,
  height: 300,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#242124',
      color: '#f0af4d'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#333333',
      color: '#c2c2c2',
      links: '#f7bc63'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: true,
    live: true,
    hashtags: true,
    timestamp: true,
    avatars: true,
    toptweets: true,
    behavior: 'default'
  }
}).render().start();
</' + 'script> ');   
 }

 else {
      document.write('<' + 'script>
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'search',
  search: '@BigNotch',
  interval: 6000,
  title: 'Follow Me On Twitter',
  subject: 'BigNotch',
  width: 180,
  height: 300,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#17d1ff',
      color: '#ff8fda'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#ededed',
      color: '#383838',
      links: '#ff8aed'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: true,
    live: true,
    hashtags: true,
    timestamp: true,
    avatars: true,
    toptweets: true,
    behavior: 'default'
  }
}).render().start();
</' + 'script> ');

  }

      }
```

Comment: I don't think that makes a difference, but why not just source the script? e.g. `<script src="mysourceurl" type="text/javascript></script>`

Comment: I just updated the post. I"m using it to change the widget depending on time of day.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* do that, but you'll need to be sure that you break up the text `</script>` within the `document.write` call, because otherwise the browser will treat it as the end of the script tag that the `document.write` call is within. The usual way to do that is to either break the word up:

```
...blah blah blah</" + "script>");
```

or put a backslash in front of the forward slash:

```
...blah blah blah<\/" + "script>");
```

It is perhaps paranoid of me, but I do it (the first bit) for opening script tags as well.

In terms of whether you do it with one `document.write` call or two, it doesn't matter. `document.write` adds to the text stream that will be parsed by the HTML parser. It doesn't matter whether you write it all out at once or use a hundred individual calls to do it.

**Update**: Some points on the code you added to the question:

1. The code won't parse, you're using `'` as the quote character for your `document.write` call, but you're also using it for strings within the code you're writing. Which means that the first `'` within the code (which is after "type:") will end the `document.write` string.
2. Remember that `document.write` only works during the initial load of a page, as part of the parsing sequence. You can't call `document.write` later, in response to an event (or rather, if you do, the odds are very low that it will do what you want — it will try to replace the entire contents of the page). In the code you added to the question, you're defining a function `changTwitter` but never calling it. You'd have to call it to do anything.

Instead of outputting a completely different script, why not just use code within the script to adjust the color by time of day? Something like:

```
<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<script>
(function() {
    var currentTime = new Date().getHours()
        shellColor,
        shellBackground,
        tweetColor,
        tweetBackground,
        linkColor;    

    if (7 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 17) {
        shellColor = /*...whatever*/;
        shellBackground = /*...whatever*/;
        tweetColor = /*...whatever*/;
        tweetBackground = /*...whatever*/;
        linkColor = /*...whatever*/;
    }
    else {
        shellColor = /*...whatever*/;
        shellBackground = /*...whatever*/;
        tweetColor = /*...whatever*/;
        tweetBackground = /*...whatever*/;
        linkColor = /*...whatever*/;
    }
    new TWTR.Widget({
      version: 2,
      type: 'search',
      search: '@blahblah',
      interval: 6000,
      title: 'Follow Me On Twitter',
      subject: 'blahblah',
      width: 180,
      height: 300,
      theme: {
        shell: {
          background: shellBackground,
          color: shellColor
        },
        tweets: {
          background: tweetBackground,
          color: tweetColor,
          links: linkColor
        }
      },
      features: {
        scrollbar: false,
        loop: true,
        live: true,
        hashtags: true,
        timestamp: true,
        avatars: true,
        toptweets: true,
        behavior: 'default'
      }
    }).render().start();
})();
</script>
```

Comment: I want to be able to switch the widget out with different colors depending on what time of day it is : )

Comment: I have the variable and everything set up already, the whole script is written, but I can an error on the document.write <- line.

Comment: @Josh: I've updated the answer. You really, really don't want to output a completely different `script` tag just to change the colors. It's *code*, branch *within* the code. Use variables. Have a party. ;-)

Comment: I know it'd sound a bit dramatic and it is: I thank you from the bottom of my heart for your comment on breaking up the text </script>

Answer (score 0):

Just put the code in a separate javascript file, and include it with **`<script src="name_you_saved_it_under.js"></script>`** (put that in the `<head>` of whatever HTML document you want to include it in.

Answer (score -2):

Using JQuery you could implement the following solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

/**
 * Function to load funcions dynamically
 * by inserting a scrip tag into the head section
 *
 * @params      <String> path to script
 * @return        none.
 */
function load_script(src) {

    // docorate an empty elemend node with the correct 
    // script source and then append it to the head section
    $('<script><\/script>').attr('src', src).appendTo($('head')[0]);

}

</script>
```

PS: This script has not been test but should be close to what you need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: you would then load a script by calling load_script('js/foo.js');

Comment: `<script/>` is shorter and also works to create a new tag using jQuery.

Comment: i know this but it is not considered good practice as per w3 specifications. You should always teach best practice, hence the shortcut is not always the better solution.

Comment: Hey, I updated the post, so you guys could get a better understanding of what i'm trying to accomplish